# Visual Studio 2019 Apply Suggestion Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellicode

Visual Studio sometimes makes suggestions based on recent edits which can be really useful at times.

[image]

However always having to press `Alt + Enter` and scroll all the way to the bottom to apply these suggestions isn't really the best workflow. Especially when applying the same suggestion multiple times in different places it can get quite annoying.

So I was wondering: Is there a keyboard shortcut to apply suggestions that I don't know of? As this is feature is pretty new I wasn't able to find much about it online.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I wanted to let you know that we have seen you feedback and think about short-cuts.